# Reglas Firebase write/PUSH no funcionan

Tags: firebase, post, realtime-database

Necesito que el usuario, sólo cuando esté autenticado, pueda subir unos datos a la BBDD de Firebase. Se llama `infoUser`

Estas reglas sí funcionan, por lo que no es un problema del código:

````
    "rules": {
      "infoUser": {
        "$uid": {
           ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
           ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
         }
       },
      "articulos": {
          ".read": true,
          ".write": "auth != null"
       }
    }
  }```

Pero se supone que éstas son las reglas que debería de usar, y no funciona. Salta el siguiente error: 
*401 (Unauthorized)
{error: 'Permission denied'}*


   ```{
"rules": {
  "infoUser": {
      "$uid": {
       ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
           ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
    }
  },
  "articulos": {
     ".read": true,
       ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
}```


Action setInfoUusario que sube el objeto a la BBDD


  ```async setInfoUsuario({commit, state}, infoUser) {
    try{
      const res = await fetch(`https://tienda.europe- 
        west1.firebasedatabase.app/infoUser/${state.user.localId}.json`, {
        method: 'POST', //Post genera un id aleatorio, 'PUT' no
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(infoUser)
      }) 

      const dataDB = await res.json()
      console.log(dataDB)
    }catch(error){
      console.log(error)
    }
    commit('setInfoUsuario', infoUser)
  }```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faltaba por añadir el idToken (Token de seguridad) a la url de llamada a firebase: `${state.user.idToken}`

Por lo que la url correcta quedaría así:
`https://tienda.europe west1.firebasedatabase.app/infoUser/${state.user.localId}.json?auth=${state.user.idToken}`